# How can I change the width attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css

I manually changed in the chrome browsers developer mode the style attribute, which has the desired effect. By entering

```
element.style {
   width: 900px;
}
```

After that the manipulated div appears as:

```
<div id="rte-savebar" class="aui-toolbar" style="width: 900px;">
```

Now I'm trying the same effect with javascript using this command:

```
document.getElementById("rte-savebar").style="width:900px;";
```

which seems to have  has no effect at all.

What do I need to do in order to change the width in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("rte-savebar").style.width = "900px";
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do it by accessing the width attribute specifically, try this:

```
document.getElementById("rte-savebar").style.width="900px";
```